Apple Magic Keyboard and the "e" key and spacebar have stopped working
I saw a similar question but there were no answers posted. I have an Apple Magic Keyboard and the "e" key and spacebar have stopped working. I have tried both Bluetooth and wired connection and I have tried to use the keyboard on another computer but was experiencing the same issue. I've checked all the keyboard and accessibility settings on my Mac. Still not working. Pressing the shift key does nothing for me.

Open the keyboard viewer.

If the keys are mapped correctly virtually and you can press them with the pointer, you need a hardware repair.

